# Activate Communities Settings: "Allow using standard external profiles for self-registration and user creation." in a scratch org config file

Tags: community, salesforcedx, metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli, winter20

Since Winter20, we have some test classes failing because of new Community Setting **[Allow using standard external profiles for self-registration and user creation.](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_networks_standard_external_profile_cruc.htm)**

The problem is that we have automated tests performed on scratch orgs fully generated by a Jenkins build, so we have no way to manually update the configuration (cf screenshot 1) , as it is a headless job

I tried to find the **right configuration value for project-scratch-def** , but it is [not documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_communitiessettings.htm), and not even related to [metadata WSDL file](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsdl/blob/master/resources/metadata.wsdl) (cf screenshot 2)

Please a super hero could save us from this new "gift" provided by Salesforce Winter20 platform upgrade, and find a **workaround to activate  *Allow using standard external profiles for self-registration and user creation* only using scripts and no manual action** ? <3

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's undocumented but it is available as `enableOotbProfExtUserOpsEnable` property in the communities settings metadata as of v47 (Winter '20). If you select the `Allow using standard external profiles for self-registration and user creation` checkbox and then retrieve the settings metadata using this package

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Communities</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

you'll see the following response (redacted below for brevity)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CommunitiesSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    ... 
    <enableOotbProfExtUserOpsEnable>true</enableOotbProfExtUserOpsEnable>
    ...
</CommunitiesSettings>
```

You should be able to update it.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks <3

Answer (score 4):

In addition to identigral great answer, here is the corresponding code for scratch org creation (project-scratch-def.json)

```
"settings": {
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true,
        "enableOotbProfExtUserOpsEnable": true
    },
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for posting this. Fixed the problem for me (once I updated SFDX to the latest version to get API 47 automatically).